# Use of conditional operator to select which object calls a particular method?

Tags: java, coding-style, conditional-operator

I have two collections, and items that are added to one or the other of those collections based on whether some criteria is met.

Somewhat inadvertantly, I stumbled on the fact that it is legal to write

```
(test(foo) ? cOne : cTheOther).add(foo);
```

instead of

```
if (test(foo)) {
 cOne.add(foo);
} else {
 cTheOther.add(foo);
}
```

While the first makes me feel clever (always a plus), I'm not sure about longer term readability, maintainability, etc.  The basic advantage I see is that if I know I'm always going to be doing the same thing, it becomes one location to change a method (instead of two, or perhaps many if I'm implementing [a switch statement via conditional operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917718/are-multiple-conditional-operators-in-this-situation-a-good-idea)).  The main disadvantage occurs when that becomes not the case (i.e., I need add a method call to some cases and not others).

**What pros and cons of the two methods (or other solutions) do you see?**

If you don't think this particular instance of using the conditional operator to set which object to call a method with is the right choice, are there cases where it is reasonable?

Comment: You say "class to call method on" - but it sounds like you mean "object." If `cOne` and `cTheOther` are classes then they are instances of the `Class` object. Is this the case?

Comment: ah, sorry, I do mean objects.  Will correct.

Comment: Also, answerers please keep in mind: the question is what do you see as pros and cons, not what would you do.

Comment: Whoever re-titled this question to "Pros and cons of Ternary Operator" made a mistake: this question is not about general pros and cons of the ternary operator, it's about a very specific case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A simpler code snippet would be

```
SomeClass component = test(foo) ? cOne : cTheOther;
component.add(foo);
```

In other words, separate the assignment from the use of it.

Comment: This one makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I considered that; could you make some arguments as to what you see as the pros and cons of this solution vs other solutions?  That's the main thrust of my question.

Comment: I believe most would call this both concise and easily readable.

Comment: It's easier to read (some might debate this) and easier to debug (hard to argue against this one). You can set a breakpoint on component.add(foo) and know what component is the moment the breakpoint is hit, whereas it is more work to see the value in a debugger if it is all on one line w/ the ternary operator.

Comment: combined with some of the other answers + comments, this settles it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: To me, this example would be harder to debug. If you get an error on `component.add(foo)`, you are not sure if the error resides in `component` initialization or `test(foo)`. Wouldn't it be easier to retrieve the value first, use it in the conditional operator, *then* add?

Answer (score 5):

As clever as the example is, readability and maintainability is always the smartest idea.

In regards to the conditional operator, you should only have a maximum of two values, if your condition goes beyond that maximum it may become unreadable. Conditional operators are not a standard way of dealing with different values.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not sure the ternary solution is more or less readable, maintainable, etc than others.  Could you make some arguments as to why you think it isn't compared to others?

Comment: I updated my answer to include some arguments, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks; relative to multiple values, I do think ternary operators can have a place ala: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917718/are-multiple-conditional-operators-in-this-situation-a-good-idea

Comment: You can use ternary operators for more than just two values, I was just pointing out that its not a standard way. In the end, no matter what answers you get, as long as you stay consistent with your choice, you should be fine with either-or.

Answer (score 1):

I am against the long-hand calling of the function in each branch of the if statement, because it's not always clear whether it's happenstance that the function to be called is the same and it's two places to change if you ever need to change the called function (okay, 'add' is an easy case).  For that reason, I would normally assign the correct object to a variable (usually in an if statement, as there's usually a little other stuff going on too) but pull all common code outside the conditional.

Comment: Worse is when they are very slightly different, then you don't know if it's deliberate or a bug :(.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional operators used for this purpose is fairly rare so the eye isn't really looking for it.

I like my Java code to look consistent, so that me and future maintainers can easily spot things like branches, too much complexity, etc. Since I use ifs elsewhere, I can usually absorb the cost of doing it over using a conditional.

If I'm using a language where I'm doing lots of "tricks" via expressions, such as Python, that's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way is:

```
final boolean    result;
final Collection c;

result = test(foo);

if(result)
{
    c = cOne;;
} 
else 
{
    c = cOther;;
}

c.add(foo);
```

First off I don't like making calls and not assigning the value to temp variable (the test(foo) call) for two reasons:

1. it is easier to debug (System.out.println, or even the debugger - if the method has side effects then just looking at it in a debugger will call it again - thus causing the side effects).
2. even if there are no side effects, it discourages you from calling it more than once, which make the code more efficient.  The compiler/hotspot should deal with the removal of the unneeded temp variable.

Secondly I don't like having code where, if you blur your eyes, it looks the same.  Having cOne.add(foo) and cOther.add(foo) "look" the same if you "blur" your eyes.  If, for example, you were changing it to a List and using add(int, E) instead of add(E) then you only have one place to change the code, which means less change of making a mistake (like cOne.add(1, foo) and cOther.add(2, foo) when they should both be add(1, foo)).

EDIT (based on the comment)

There are a couple of choices, it depends on how you have the code layed out.  I would probably go with something like:

```
private Collection<Whatever> chooseCollection(final Whatever             foo,
                                              final Collection<Whatever> a,
                                              final Collection<Whatever> b)
{
    final boolean              result;
    final Collection<Whatever> c;

    result = test(foo);

    // could use a conditional - I just hate using them
    if(result)
    {
        c = a;
    }
    else
    {
        c = b;
    }

    return (c);
}
```

and then have something like:

```
for(......)
{
    final Collection<Whatever> c;
    final Whatever             foo;

    foo = ...;
    c = chooseCollection(foo, cOne, cOther);
    c.add(foo;
}
```

Essentially I make a method for anything inside of a { } block if it makes sense (and usually it does).  I like to have a lot of small methods.

Comment: I understand your points; in my particular case, I'm testing a series of foo's; would you simply put your snippet inside a loop?  Or would you de-final the temp variables and pull them outside the loop?

Comment: I always try to make the variables have as small a scope as possible, so I would keep them in the loop if possible.  Have a look at the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for the update; your answer is inconsistent with the way I usually code, but it's useful for me to see other perspectives laid out.

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem with using conditional operators is when the arguments start to become more complex. For example, if the following line throws a NullPointerException:

```
String aString = obj1.getValue() == null ? obj2.getString() : obj1.getValue().getString();
```

which of the the three dereferences is causing the NPE? `obj1`, `obj2` or `obj1.getValue()` Sometimes it might be possible through inference in the preceding code to work it out, but not always…

That said, compare the following two pieces of code:

```
final String aString = obj1 == null ? "default" : obj1.getString();
```

vs

```
final String aString;
if (obj1 == null) {
  aString = "default";
} else {
  aString = obj1.getString();
}
```

Most people would argue that the conditional is simpler to read, and it is certainly more concise.

Now, with that out of the way, would I use a conditional to call a method? No, it adds a lot of visual complexity, and one has to remember, that debugging is twice as hard as writing code. That means that the simpler the code is, the simpler it is for you, or someone else, to understand it in six months time. I would be more than happy to use the two line version in the accepted answer.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it doesn't seem to address the specific question I posed.  I think that may have a bit to do with the changes others made to the title, which made the question seem to be a very broad query about the ? operator, which it is not.

Comment: @Carl: You are right, this addresses more the original question title, than your question text. I guess the title slanted my way of thinking. I have updated the answer to directly address your question.

Comment: @Ether: Thanks for the edit; You are correct of course, in theory there could be another ternary, even if now there is not. The improved precision in the answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the "full", long version is a little bit more readable and definitely better for maintenance in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first one  (Or the intermediate solution by matt). It is just shorter. If the conditional operator is used rather often in your project, people get used to it and "readability" increases.

Or in other words: if you are used to Perl, you can easily read it.

Comment: ha, I am used to Perl; how ever did you guess? :)  The ternary operator is indeed used frequently in the project, however this is the first time I've stumbled across using it this way.  I am looking at some other locations that would be reasonable to refactor to this type of construction, however.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what matt b said, you could go one step further and use this format, when you decide to use the conditional operator:

```
SomeClass component = test(foo) 
   ? cOne 
   : cTheOther;
component.add(foo);
```

It gives the code more of an if-else feel, and makes it easier to read.

Comment: I prefer a slight variation, where the test condition and colon are moved to the second line; another test condition and ternary operation can then be appended (with appropriate indentation) to create a sort of switch-case structure (the question has a link to another SOQ that discusses this structure).  I don't use that frequently, but I do use it enough that I try to make most other ternary operations obey that structure so it's not outlandish elsewhere in the code.