# Declare class object with parameters without using if...else

Tags: c++

I am new in C++ and try to write a cache simulator. The constructor of class CACHE is

```
CACHE (int, int, int, int, CACHE *);   //declare
```

and in the `main()`, I am trying to create objects according to some variable:

```
int main()
{
       if ( L2_size == 0 )      //only one level of cache   
       {
        CACHE L1(L1_size, blocksize, L1_assoc, inclusion, 0);
       }
       else                     //2 level of caches
       {
        CACHE L2(L2_size, blocksize, L2_assoc, inclusion, 0);
        CACHE L1(L1_size, blocksize, L1_assoc, inclusion, &L2);
       }
}
```

The issue with this is that I am not able to access L1 and L2 since their scope are inside if...else.

Besides, I've tried using ? : operator to implement this, still get error:

no match for ternary operator.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Include an example of how `L2` and `L1` will be used.  As an example, if `L2_size == 0`, there is no `L2`, so what is supposed to happen to code that tries to use `L2`?  Or is this just about `L1`?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this post?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917718/are-multiple-conditional-operators-in-this-situation-a-good-idea

Comment: if L2_size == 0, there is no object for L2 cache

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
    CACHE *L2 = 0;
    CACHE *L1 = 0;


    if (L2_size)
    {
        L2 = new CACHE(L2_size, blocksize, L2_assoc, inclusion, 0);
    }
    L1 = new CACHE(L1_size, blocksize, L1_assoc, inclusion, L2);
```

I'm sure there are other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks Mats. It seems that L1 is always pointing to L2 according to your code.

Comment: +1, and @ARGOS it isn't. `*L2` is 0 (null) unless `L2_size` of a non-zero nature creates a new CACHE and assigned it to `*L2`. If `L2_size` is zero, the `*L2` will be NULL on the creation of L1, exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a container such as `std::list` or `std::vector` before your `if` statement and just push_back as many CACHE objects as you need.

Example:

```
int main()
    {
       std::list<CACHE> caches;
       if (L2_size == 0)
       {
          caches.push_front(CACHE(L1_size, blocksize, L1_assoc, inclusion, 0));
       }
       else
       {
          caches.push_front(CACHE(L2_size, blocksize, L2_assoc, inclusion, 0);
          caches.push_front(CACHE(L1_size, blocksize, L1_assoc, inclusion, &(*caches.begin());
       }
    }
```

Whichever method you use, the idea is to create the stack variable (the `list`, `pointer`, or whatever) before your `if` statement, so that it stays in scope.

Comment: @Mats Edited. New version any good? It does the job, although it's only suited to a two level cache scenario, but that's what the OP wants anyway.

Comment: @Mats Petersson, L2's address is passed to L1, there is a CACHE pointer in L1, which points to L2

Comment: @ARGOS Mats was referring to my pre-edited version, which neglected to pass L2's address to L1.

Comment: Yes, that would work. However, there is no need to do this, since the L1 has a pointer to L2, so you don't need to push it onto a list... ;)

Comment: @Mats True. I only chose list so that the container wouldn't have to be resized. Also, I started out without realising the caches needed to point to each other, so a list seemed like a decent generic solution (i.e. it could be expanded trivially to include more than two caches).